# Is it safe to share expo account?

Tags: react-native, expo

I’d like to give my client my username and password to check beta app version on Expo app.
Does that risk exposing source code of the app?

Answer (score 4):

If your client was really motivated, they could theoretically access your app through a modified version of the Expo client, and log the source code of your app.

But practically, there's no risk that somebody using the standard expo client, cli, or web interface would be able to see your source code, although if you're developing for android, you should probably just [publish the app and give them the link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/distribution/release-channels/). Since you're probably trying to circumvent Expo's [iOS restrictions](https://blog.expo.io/upcoming-limitations-to-ios-expo-client-8076d01aee1a), giving them your account is probably harmless.

Comment: Also, could someone clarify why exactly people consider this a poor question? Doesn't it fall under [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?